# Remove quotes around strings

Tags: python

```
array = format([
    v if v is not None else "*" for v in self._tree.bfs_order_star()
])
```

The code above returns a string in the following format:

**Output:** `[ 10, 5, 15, '*', '*','*', 20 ]`

How can I change it so the *(stars), none-values, are not surrounded by quotes? I tried the following without success.

```
array = format([
    v if v is not None else "*" for v in self._tree.bfs_order_star()
]).strip('"\'')
```

Comment: Do you want `[10, 5, 15, *, *, *, 20]`? That's not a valid python expression

Comment: The `'*'` means that it's a string. If you print the string, it will be just `*`

Comment: string will always have [quotes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-constants) , instead you can use `None`

Comment: A list can only contain values. Values can be strings, numbers, or nested lists or dicts. A star is none of these. The quotes are not part of the value, they are how strings are represented in Python.

Comment: @Chris hmm okay i want to print the values in specific way. I want the stars to be treated like one element. The problem is that the quotes are also treated like one unique element, that's why I want to get rid of them.

Comment: Sounds like you will be using the whole list as a single str afterward? Do you want something like `str([ 10, 5, 15, '*', '*','*', 20 ]).replace("'", "")`?

Comment: Yeah maybe, best solution yet seems to be just using None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `replace()` method to remove the quotes when printing:

```
#Convert list to string and replace/remove specific characters.
str(lst).replace("[character to replace/remove]", "[character to replace with or leave empty to remove.]")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class/object whose representation actually is just a star:

```
class Star:
    def __repr__(self):
        return '*'
```

A demo:

```
>>> print([1, '*', 2])
[1, '*', 2]
>>> print([1, Star(), 2])
[1, *, 2]
```